# Huawei HMS initialize without Json file

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

Is it possible to initialize HMS without a `agconnect-services.json` and provide the keys at runtime?

Using a similar service (Fcm) we can initialize an app:

```kotlin
val builder = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
          .setApiKey(apiKey)
          .setGcmSenderId(senderId)
          .setProjectId(project)
          .setApplicationId(appId)
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, builder.build())
```

Therefore, you can use it without need of a `json` file to be parsed.

Is there a similar solution for this using `HMS` and `AppGallery`?

**BTW**, I'm trying to implement **PushKit**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

- Push Kit

You can add the following code in your manifest file:

```
<meta-data        
    android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid"        
    <!-- Replace value xxx with the actual appid.-->         
    android:value="appid=xxx">         
</meta-data>
```

Currently, HMS does not provide a unified solution for code-based initialization. However, some kits support code-based initialization.

- [Map Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mapsinitializer-0000001050150366-V5):

`MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your API Key");`

- [Site Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/api-searchservicefactory-0000001050154715-V5)：

`SearchService searchService = SearchServiceFactory.create(this, "API key");`

- [ML Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/mlapplication-0000001050167420-V5):

`MLApplication.getInstance().setApiKey("your ApiKey");`

If you use only these kits, you do not need to integrate the JSON file. Instead, you can complete code-based initialization through the API key.

We will analyze and discuss your requirement for a unified code-based initialization solution and reply to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to implement **HiAI** through **DevEco** you can run application without **agconnect-services.json** file. To know more use the [link](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0202369427655700351&fid=0101187876626530001).

In another way you can try **Coding Assistant**, it will do automatic Environment Configuration for some kits. Currently it will support Push Kit and there is no need to download **agconnect-services.json** manually.
To know more use the [link](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201339927413030084&fid=0101188387844930001)